# Isomorphism of Grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, self-learning

I want to prove that two CW complexes $\mathrm{Gr}_{n}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ and $\mathrm{Gr}_{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ are isomorphic to one another. I'm pretty sure I can just show that the number of $r$-cells in each of the complexes are equal. The isomorphism should follow from this. However, I'm a little unsure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $f \colon \mathrm{Gr}_{n}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}) \to \mathrm{Gr}_{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ given by $f(X) = X^\perp$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: It is sufficient to prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism to obtain my result? We know that $\mathrm{Gr}_{n}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ is a manifold of dimension $nk$, so I would only have to show that $f$ is continuous over open neighborhoods?

Comment: What sort of result are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Simply an isomorphism between $\mathrm{Gr}_{n}$ and $\mathrm{Gr}_{k}$.

Comment: An isomorphism in what category?

Comment: Ideally in the category of CW-complexes.

Comment: That would be a homeomorphism though, right?

Comment: Yes, this should work, although I have proven the isomorphism without any sort of hypothesis on the $r$-cells themselves, which seems strange to me.

Comment: Well, if you prefer, there is a natural way to associate the cells in $\mathrm{Gr}_{n}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ with those in $\mathrm{Gr}_{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ by thinking about the Schubert cells in the context of the map I gave above. It's a little more work to write down all of the details, but it can be done. You should try it!